# After cross compiling, how to change the source directory name for make install?

Tags: linux, makefile, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I cross compiled a library on Ubuntu, and I copied the build directory to my Raspberry pi. However, it won't let me do make install on raspberry pi because all the paths are according to my Ubuntu system not raspberry pi's. Is there a command to change that quickly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it depends entirely on the build system of the library itself.  if it's autotools based, you can often override specific vars like:

```
make install prefix=/usr bindir=/bin ...
```

the [automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Standard-Directory-Variables.html) documents a bunch of these standard variables.

if it's not autotool based, then you'll have to read the `Makefile` directly to see how it can be installed.  maybe it respects `DESTDIR` ?

```
make install DESTDIR=/some/other/place
```

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood my problem. I am not trying to change the install directory but the src directory. On raspberry pi, it says "The source directory "/home/ethan/raspberrypi/pcl" does not exist." because it is the path on my ubuntu system. I need to make it "/home/pi/pcl" somehow without going into every single file. Or should I have done something different when cross-compiling on my Ubuntu to avoid this problem in the first place?

Comment: what exactly are the commands you ran ?  did you have to run `./configure` ?